# OpenFL C++ Error: Could not guess MINGW_ROOT

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop, openfl, nme

I am new to OpenFL and were trying to get it to work for the first time. I have installed haxe, lime and openfl via command prompt, and installed Visual Studio Express 2010 using lime setup windows. But when I try to compile a brand new OpenFL project in Flash Develop targeting c++, I get the error "Error: Could not guess MINGW_ROOT (tried [c:/MinGW]) - please set explicitly".

Anyone had this problem before? or is there anything I have to configurate?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact you try to execute to build our project?

Answer (score 3):

Hi your system is not yet setup for windows, check this link:

http://www.openfl.org/documentation/advanced-setup/platforms/setup-windows/

Basically you need to install Visual C++ and other stuff, luckily openfl have this automated. Just open the command prompt where openfl is and type:

```
openfl setup windows
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry I forgot the most important part, close FlashDevelop and re-open it.

Comment: I did the windows setup on two machines yesterday, first one just needed a FlashDevelop restart, the second a full reboot.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants to know, it seems to work by installing mingw and setting the environment path. My mingw comes from Qt installation.
from console you can do something like

```
setx MINGW_ROOT "C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\bin"
```

or

```
setx MINGW_ROOT "C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\bin" /M
```